# Run React useEffect if the inputed string is the same as before

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to make my own useFetch hook.

```js
export const useFetch = <T extends unknown>(
    url: string,
    options?: RequestInit
) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    const [response, setResponse] = useState<T>();

    useEffect(() => {
        const controller = new AbortController();
        setLoading(true);
        fetch(url, { ...options, signal: controller.signal })
            .then((res) => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    setError(true);
                } else {
                    setError(false);
                }
                return res.json();
            })
            .then((json) => {
                setLoading(false);
                setResponse((json as unknown as JSONResponse).content as T);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                setLoading(false);
                setError(true);
            });

        return () => {
            controller.abort();
        };
    }, [url, options]);

    return { loading, error, response };
};
```

The fetch runs every time the URL changes. My problem is that I use it like this in my Home.tsx

```js
    const [url, setUrl] = useState('')

    const roomIDRef = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>;

    const { error, response, loading } = useFetch<ExistsRoom>(
        url
    );

        const joinRoom = async () => {
        const id = roomIDRef.current.value;
        if (id === '') {
            return;
        }
            setUrl(() => `http://localhost:8808/api/v1/room/exists?id=${id}`);
    };
```

The user has to input an id and press a button to run this fetch. It should check if the room with this id exists. My problem is if the user tries to check the room with the id=test and the request will be made he gets his response. But if he tries to press the button again, which will mean he will request the same id and therefore the same url it won't fetch again because the url doesn't change.
Can I work around this somehow?

I tried to add a random query parameter to the URL and it works

```
setUrl(() => `http://localhost:8808/api/v1/room/exists?id=${id}&t=${Date.now().toString()}`);
```

but I don't think this is the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: If you don't cache the responses, you shouldn't optimize and prevent fetching of same Ids. Just remove the dependence on `[url, options]` on the `useEffect`

Comment: If I just leave the dependencies empty it will fetch endlessly. I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter and every time that use clicks the button again, raise the counter. Add counter to dependencies.

Comment: Is there not a cleaner way

Comment: Even better, use just bool isFetchNeeded and if fetch required again set it to true. Then set it to false once’s fetched